# Open javascript bookmarklets from Quicksilver in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, quicksilver, bookmarklet

I finally made the switch from Safari to Chrome a few days ago, and I haven't looked back.  There is one issue I've been running into though -- I used to be able to open javascript bookmarklets with [Quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/), and they would run in my currently open tab in Safari.  So for example I have the following bookmarklet for [Readability](https://www.readability.com/):

```
javascript:(function()%7BreadStyle='style-newspaper';readSize='size-large';readMargin='margin-narrow';_readability_script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');_readability_script.type='text/javascript';_readability_script.src='http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/js/readability.js?x='+(Math.random());document.getElementsByTagName('head')%5B0%5D.appendChild(_readability_script);_readability_css=document.createElement('LINK');_readability_css.rel='stylesheet';_readability_css.href='http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/css/readability.css';_readability_css.type='text/css';_readability_css.media='all';document.getElementsByTagName('head')%5B0%5D.appendChild(_readability_css);_readability_print_css=document.createElement('LINK');_readability_print_css.rel='stylesheet';_readability_print_css.href='http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/css/readability-print.css';_readability_print_css.media='print';_readability_print_css.type='text/css';document.getElementsByTagName('head')%5B0%5D.appendChild(_readability_print_css);%7D)();
```

And before I could open this in Quicksilver and execute the "Run Javascript" action, and it would run the javascript in the current tab (usually some blog article I was reading).

Now these javascript bookmarklets don't seem to work.  I added The following to `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Info.plist` in the `CFBundleURLTypes` array.  Now Chrome gets focus, but the javascript doesn't run.

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>Javascript URLs</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>javascript</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

**Note**: I can't get this to work with [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) either

Answer (score 2):

"Run Javascript" action does not work for Google Chrome before some change made to QS and a new Chrome qsplugin.

However, as long as Chrome does come with AppleScript support, you should be able to write an AppleScript action to do the same thing.